# Why did my cilantro leaves get white and patchy?

Tags: diagnosis, herbs, cilantro

I grow my cilantro on my kitchen counter with a grow light above. My cilantro starts out looking lush and green but quickly some leaves start getting white patches. It doesn't seem to kill my plant but it doesn't look appetizing. I'm using a glass bulb to water it (I refill it each time it empties). Any ideas?

If you need more information let me know.

[image]

Comment: Etiolation from too little light? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etiolation

Comment: How old is this plant?  They don't live long ...

Comment: It happens to all my cilantro plants. I've bought 4 so far and this has happened to all of them. This one is roughly I'd say a few months old.

Comment: I don't think it etiolation for I have a growing lamp that turns on and off periodically and it sits by a south west facing window. My cilantro still grows and my other plants aren't getting any of the symptoms of etiolation.

Comment: Hi Tolure. By any chance did you find out what caused this? If not, are there any more details that could be added to help get what you need? If so, would you care to write up an answer? That way we could learn, and also clear an "unanswered" question off the site! Thanks

Comment: No I still don't know. Ask away I'll answer any questions that might help.